# ngGrid Export to csv using the cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv, ng-grid

I have used the ng-grid export to CSV plugin that comes with ng-grid (using version 2.0.14). It works for the data, but when I use cellTemplates to format the data, that is not carried over to the CSV.

Does any of you have a good idea to get the data in the CSV to reflect what the user see in the grid?